# Git keeps asking for authentication

Tags: git, authentication, github

I have a private repo on GitHub to store my programming notes and exercises.

I use two computers to access my repo: my personal laptop and my work computer.

As per GitHub's documentation, in order to avoid getting asked for credentials each time you want to push/pull/fetch to/from origin, you should use `gh auth login` command and do it once and for all.

This worked with my PC, but doesn't seem to with my work computer: as a matter of fact, although I've logged in with my PAT as per GitHub's new security controls, git keeps asking me to authenticate in the aforementioned scenarios.

Note: I've read that one problem might be HTTPS. Well, I don't think so, because I cloned my repo on my laptop following doc's instructions and it worked, so...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using https, check your *credential helpers*. Your default credential helper is OS-specific. Some credential helpers are included with Git, and pure add-ons exist as well. Your configured helper(s) is/are the one(s) that supply the credentials. If you're using ssh, check your ssh configuration: Git simply *runs* ssh here, but there's one caveat, which is that Git-for-Windows includes a separate ssh implementation in case your Windows system lacks one entirely or has a faulty one. So you might need to configure *which* ssh to run.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you probably missed a step while linking your Git to your Github.

Follow the instructions below (taken from [here](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-setting-up-git))to correctly link your local Git to Github with SSH without having to enter your credentials each time. (assuming you already created your Github account). Try to see which steps you missed.

## Step 1: Initialise Git credentials in your CLI

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "yourname@example.com"
```

If you opted to use the private GitHub email address, the second command will look something like this:

```
git config --global user.email "123456789+odin@users.noreply.github.com"
```

Remember to use your own private GitHub email here.

To verify that things are working properly, enter these commands and verify whether the output matches your name and email address.

```
git config --get user.name
git config --get user.email
```

**macOS Users**: Run these two commands to tell git to ignore `.DS_Store` files, which are automatically created when you use Finder to look into a folder. `.DS_Store` files are invisible to the user and hold custom attributes or metadata (like thumbnails) for the folder, and if you don’t configure GitHub to ignore them, pesky `.DS_Store` files will show up in your commits.

```
echo .DS_Store >> ~/.gitignore_global
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

## Step 2: Create an SSH Key

GitHub uses SSH keys to allow you to upload to your repository **without having to type in your username and password every time.**

First, we need to see if you have an Ed25519 algorithm SSH key already installed. Type this into the terminal and check the output with the information below:

```
ls ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

If a message appears in the console containing the text “No such file or directory”, then you do not yet have an Ed25519 SSH key, and you will need to create one. If no such message has appeared in the console output, you can proceed to step 3.

To create a new SSH key, run the following command inside your terminal. The -C flag followed by your email address ensures that GitHub knows who you are.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C <youremail>
```

Don't include the angle brackets.
When it prompts you for a location to save the generated key, just push Enter.
Next, it will ask you for a password; enter one if you wish, but it’s not required.

## Step 3: Link Your SSH Key with GitHub

Now, you need to tell GitHub what your SSH key is so that you can push your code without typing in a password every time.

First, you’ll navigate to where GitHub receives our SSH key. Log into GitHub and click on your profile picture in the top right corner. Then, click on Settings in the drop-down menu.

Next, on the left-hand side, click SSH and GPG keys. Then, click the green button in the top right corner that says New SSH Key. Name your key something that is descriptive enough for you to remember where it came from. Leave this window open while you do the next steps.

Now you need to copy your public SSH key. To do this, we’re going to use a command called cat to read the file to the console. (Note that the .pub file extension is important in this case.)

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

Highlight and copy the output, which starts with ssh-ed25519 and ends with your email address.

Now, go back to GitHub in your browser window and paste the key you copied into the key field. Then, click Add SSH key.

## Step 4 : Testing your key

Follow the directions in this article from [GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection) to verify your SSH connection (Don’t forget to omit the $ when you copy and paste the code!). You should see this response in your terminal: `Hi username! You’ve successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access`. Don’t let GitHub’s lack of providing shell access trouble you.

Comment: Note that nothing in step 1 has anything to do with *authentication*, so you can do this step whenever you like (perhaps after step 4).